# Convert Java Object to JSON for okhttp body

Tags: java, okhttp

I have the following code:

```java
ApolloRequestObj obj = ApolloRequestObj.builder()
    .api_key("3434")
    .domains(List.of("test"))
    .build();

// how to send the object as a request body?
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(
    MediaType.parse("application/json"), json);

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(".......")
    .post(requestBody)
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .header("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    .build();
```

The object for request:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
private class ApolloRequestObj {
    public String api_key;
    public List < String > domains;
}
```

When I initialize the Object with some data I want to send it with payload data to a remote host. Do you know how I can send the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to take a POJO and serialize to Json, you can configure an ObjectMapper from Jackson to do this for you.

Here is a short example,

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
var jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueToString(obj); 

RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(
    MediaType.parse("application/json"), jsonString);

// rest of code here.
```

You'll need to grab the Jackson library depending on what dependency management framework you are using.

If you need escaped Json you can accomplish this by a simple string replace to add escaped quotes.